# Visual Studio Debug and Get DNS Error INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2019

Yesterday morning I started receiving the error in Internet Explorer when trying to locally debug my asp.net C# application (.net framework 4.5/Windows 10): ***There was a temporary DNS error. Try refreshing the page. Error Code: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND***

In Google Chrome and Firefox I receive the error: ***ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR***

I have tried to debug 2 other projects and they launch successfully.

I have attempted the following:

- Clean solution and rebuild
- IIS reset
- (1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt, (2) netsh winsock reset => then restart computer
- Debugging in Chrome and Firefox
- DNSFLUSH and then reboot

Thank you for any assistance you may be able to provide.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could please try the following steps:

**1)** disable any third party extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions**

and then close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder, `bin` and `obj` folder, then restart your project.

**2)** change to use another port by right-click on your project-->`Properties`-->`Web`--> change `Porject Url` to use another port like `44393`.

**3)** open Registry window and then enter `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`-->`Software`-->`Microsoft`-->`Windows`-->`CurrentVersion`-->`Internet Settings`-->`Connections`.

Then right-click on the Connections folder and rename its name to `ConnectionsX`.

**4)** open control panel--> click **User Account**--> then click Change User Account Control Settings-->make sure that you pick is the second one if counting from the top. Click OK to Save. Click Yes to confirm.

**5)** open **CMD** as **Administrator**-->type `ipconfig /flushdns`

Open **Windows PowerShell** as **Administrator** and then type:

```
 ipconfig /all > C:\ipconfiguration.txt
 netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
 netsh winsock reset
```

**Besides**, you can refer to [this solution](https://geeksadvice.com/how-to-fix-inet_e_resource_not_found-error-on-windows-10/) and [that one](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/hosting/technical-matters/inet-e-resource-not-found-error/#:%7E:text=The%20various%20error%20messages%20associated,DNS%20server%20currently%20in%20use.&text=By%20default%2C%20most%20users%20obtain,to%20enter%20the%20address%20manually.).

**In addition**, for `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`, you could try these:

open **Chrome**, delete all data caches by `Ctrl + Shift + Delete` and remember to click **All Time**-->Check the checkbox for `Cookies and other site data` and `Cached images and files`

**More steps** for the issue, you could refer to [this link](https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/how-to-fix-err-ssl-protocol-error#:%7E:text=Check%20the%20Date%20of%20Your%20System&text=When%20the%20date%20of%20your,then%20try%20opening%20the%20site.).

Comment: Good Morning Perry - Are these suggestions in order of priority or should I order them in some other way?  Thanks so very much for all the research you did on this problem!!!

Comment: You could try this suggestion one by one and it already has the priority order. We will wait for your response:)

Comment: Unfortunately these suggestions did not solve the problem.  Just to be clear, this is not a browser-specific issue as all browsers have an issue.  The error messages differ from each browser but all are indicating a problem.  Thanks again for your guidance.

Comment: It could be an Internet issue from time to time. It is quite annoying. Please try [this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1f4a9826-476a-43b0-8152-c0a5a64cd167/there-was-a-temporary-dns-error-try-refreshing-the-page-error-code-ineteresourcenotfound?forum=SP2019) :)